# Awk (or other) how to force the field number to stay the same?

Tags: bash, awk

I have an input file that contains the fallowing lines:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I
1;3312;14.025538;14.617777;0.;0.000000001;253.777023;3.232552;52487.
2;3312;13.206808;13.779518;0.;260.078461;258.954529;3.154804;52487.
3;3312;13.054019;13.491556;0.;256.126221;251.776566;3.247191;52487.
4;3312;12.556334;13.061086;0.;255.570862;254.689224;3.190753;52487.
5;3312;11.719666;11.96375;0.;100.0546;254.258652;3.220166;52487.
```

I need to always read the fields based on A, C, D and F, which is in this case $1, $3, $4 and $6. So the awk is easy:

```
awk -F";" '{print $1, $3, $4, $6}' input.txt
```

But, if the order of the letters is different, how to get to the same result? In example the order is (I just print the first line but the position of the next ones will differ too):

```
A;I;E;H;G;F;C;D;B
```

I still need to always read the fields based on A, C, D and F, but now they are $1, $9, $8 and $6. And they may vary again, from input file to input file.

Is there a way to sort the fields based on A, C, D and F, no matter their order, and, disregarding all the other fields, so I will always have something like below:

```
A;C;D;E
1;14.025538;14.617777;0.000000001
2;13.206808;13.779518;260.078461
3;13.054019;13.491556;256.126221
4;12.556334;13.061086;255.570862
5;11.719666;11.96375;100.0546
```

Comment: I would recommend - if the columns have a distinguishable pattern - to use sed for reordering the input to make it uniform. Then pipe this to awk

Comment: Is there a reason you're having long pipes of `awk`s? I'm sure `awk` is powerful enough to achieve your task in just one single call! what are you trying to achieve exactly? please expose your problem, give a sample input and wanted output.

Comment: As @gniourf_gniourf said, you need, as a start, to expose to us what the input actually looks like.

Comment: If originally B is column 2, and the input has changed, B becomes column 9. How can I force B to get back as column 2? Then I can pipe it to awk. I'll try to get a sample of my code. Why I would like A C D and F to be $1, $3, $4 and $6 is because I will pipe it to awk and that will become $1, $2, $3 and $4. Or more simple, how to force A C D and F to be column 1, 2, 3 and 4 and always like this no matter what.This way the order of the input can change but it won't matter anymore. If you see what I mean?

Comment: If you always want `$2` to be `B`, then there is no need to read an input file, just set `$2="B"`.  If that isn't what you meant, then you need to show us what the input actually looks like.

Comment: I will try that, if it works then it's very simple. Sometimes it gets so complicated in my head. I edited my question I think it makes more sense this way.

Comment: pluse uno for listening to recommendations and adding sample data and required output. Good luck.

Comment: Actually this is not the way, but thanks for the tip. It was so opposite, I always want B to the same variable. Thanks Shellter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ awk -F\; -vOFS=\; 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) h[$i]=i} {print $h["A"], $h["C"], $h["D"], $h["F"]}'`

On the first line of input, record a mapping from all column headings to their indices.
Afterwards, in all rules, refer to fields by heading name instead of index.

Comment: Nicely done; add `-v OFS=\;` to also separate the _output_ fields with `;` instances.

Comment: I have no choice but to say thank you thank you! This awk command will stay in my top 5, so useful. It makes things so much easier this way. I just replace A B C D and F by other variables and things are so smooth. Yes mklement0 thanks it does the job with -v OFS=\;